# Minimizing Quadratic Form with Norm and Positive Orthant Constraints

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Let $ M $ be a positive semi definite matrix.

I want to solve
$$ \arg \min_{x} {x}^{T} M x \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad \left\| x \right\| = 1, \ x \succeq 0 $$
where $ x \succeq 0 $ means each coordinate of $x$ is nonnegative.

Is there a standard approach for attacking this problem?
Without the inequality constraint, the usual approach is to expand $ x $ in the eigenvector basis of $ M $ and to notice that the solution must be the eigenvector with least eigenvalue.
Without the equality constraint, obviously the solution is $ x = \boldsymbol{0} $.

Comment: What is the nullity of $M$?

Comment: @Rodrigo we can assume $M$ is nonsingular, if that helps

Comment: If $M$ is singular, then one could use linear programming to determine if the null space and the nonnegative orthant intersect. If so, look for unit norm solution.

Comment: What about a similar case where $ \left\| x \right\|_{1} = 1 $? Then the problem can be solved easily.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the article in this - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1010294/33.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the Projected Gradient Descend for this case.
Though the problem isn't Convex it will work nicely.

The algorithm is as following:

1. Calculate the Gradient at the current point.
2. Update the solution $ x = x - 2 t M x $ where $ 2 M x $ is the Gradient of the Objective Function and $ t $ is the step size.
3. Project the output of previous step into $ {\mathbb{R}}_{+} $ by $ {x}_{i} = \max \left\{ {x}_{i}, 0 \right\} $.
4. Project the output of previous step onto the Unit Sphere by $ {x}_{i} = \frac{ {x}_{i} }{ \left\| x \right\|_{2} } $.
5. Go back to (1) (Or check validity of the point, KKT will do even the problem isn't Convex).

In a simple 2D example I created which worked pretty well:

[image]

The code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2699867 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2699867).

**Remark 001**
I'd even considering starting with the solution of the Convex Problem when you replace the equality constraint $ \left\| x \right\|_{2} = 1 $ by $ \left\| x \right\|_{1} = 1 $ (This will make the problem basically constraining $ x $ to the Unit Simplex). You can either use it as a starting point for the above algorithm or approximated solution by itself.

**Remark 002**
Another approach might be something like I did in - [Solution for $ \arg \min_{ {x}^{T} x = 1} { x}^{T} A x - {c}^{T} x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2402360/33).
Yet after each iteration of updating $ \lambda $ you should also project the output $ x $ into $ \mathbb{R}_{+} $.

Comment: Note to my self - This might be related - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2407669/33.

Comment: Regarding remark 1, even the 1 norm equals 1 is a non-convex constraint right?

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan, Yep. Any non linear equality constraint makes the problem non convex.

Comment: Why does your remark say 'I'd even considering starting with the solution of the Convex Problem when you replace the equality constraint ‖x‖2=1 by  ‖x‖1=1' then?

Comment: I wasn't clear on that. But what I meant is if you have $ x \succeq 0 $ and $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} = 1 $ then the problem become Convex as its equivalent is having $ x $ in the Unit Simplex.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $||x||_{1} \leq 1$, that equality constraint of yours looks non-convex.

Comment: Have a look at the following constraints:  $ x \succeq 0 $ and $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {x}_{i} = 1 $. Those are the constraints of being in the Unit Simplex which is a convex set.

Comment: Now, what do you think about $ x \succeq 0 $ and $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left| {x}_{i} \right| = 1 $? Do you see the equivalence when $ x \succeq 0 $?

Comment: Got it! I suppose it's non convex only in the absence of that first inequality. This would be $x \geq 0$ and $1'x=1$